# Why was Immortals so dark?

Tags: film-techniques, immortals

I watched Immortals and the whole movie seemed so dark and gloomy. I mean, the visuals are more black and yellow based than normal movies. No sun, no birds, no happiness- just night and black and killings. Why was it made this way? And is this any specific filming technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the idea was to attempt a 300-like movie by shooting and editing with particularly dark effects.

As for the dark plot line, Greek mythology did tend to be dark and such details as the three priestess' being cooked in an iron bull are accurate but this movie takes it way too far

Comment: IMO, this comes nowhere near 300! It was way better than this and actually had a good storyline. And yeah, I agree with you on the "this movie takes it way too far" part. I'll keep the question open for a couple more days and see what happens...